# check constraint sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have tables as you can see in the picture.

[image]

so what I want to do...?
I want to make a constraint that checks of the ID that can be just repetition two time and not more than that in the same table like when he does an exam 2018-01-01 he can repeat the exam after 15 days ...?
it means that have a chance to repeat the exam two times in the month, not more.

I make one

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ESAMI]
ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_ColumnD_ESEMI CHECK > 2
```

but not working.

so how can I do that?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: what you want to mean by that...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution thanks to Mr: denis.

you have first to create a function like this:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE FUNCTION DBO.ESAMI_CHECK
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @IdStudente INT
)
RETURNS INT

AS
BEGIN
    RETURN (
        SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM ESAMI WHERE IdStudente=@IdStudente
        GROUP BY IdStudente 
    )   
END
GO
```

after that you have to make the constraint like this:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ESAMI]
ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_ColumnD_ESEMI
CHECK (DBO.ESAMI_CHECK(IdStudente) <= 2)
```

that's all and it will work perfectly. thanks to all and have a good day.

Answer (score 2):

You should write:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ESAMI]
ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_ColumnD_ESEMI UNIQUE(IdEsami)
```

Comment: is the same as mine, but is not working when i add like ex: IdStudente 1, and repeat it 3 times it accepted and that not what i want i want when it more then two give a message

Comment: I guess what you want is `UNIQUE` constraint. I edited the answer.

Comment: even that is not working when i meet that is the same result, mean when i make (idstudent 1) tre time it accepted.

Comment: What you mean is that there should be at least three rows per ID?

Comment: it mean that when like Id=1 have do the exam like in this 2018-12-01 he have the right to do the exam after 15 days mean in 2018-12-16. and don't have right to do more then that in the month